# Disabled Angular routing

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

I have created a sample angular project,
when asked for routing said **YES**, so this project has routing enabled.

Now I want to disable the routing for this project just like Saying **NO** while project setup,

I did some google but could not find any solution,

Please advise How could I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: then use the `CanDeactivate` in your routing

Comment: Could you please give any example , I have just started angular so feeling bit bouncer here https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Answer (score 2):

When you selected Yes in project set-up, CLI created an `app-routing.module.ts` file. Delete it, and all references to it, including imports.

In `app.component.html`, you'll see a tag `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`... delete it too.

In `app.module.ts`, delete the entry `AppRoutingModule`, and the import for it.

That will remove routing from the application.

Comment: NB: Edit rejected as suggested edit repeats my first line "**Delete it**, and all references to it, including imports." 

Comment: Isn't there any shortcut way like any cli command to do the same, or any option to say don't use this, as I may need it again, i want to play around this

Comment: All the routing does, is render your routed component inside `<router-outlet>`, so, if you want to keep routing handy, but **not use it**, just delete/comment out `<router-outlet>` in your main `app.component.html`, that way its still there, it just doesn't do anything 